# symfony raw sql fetch -> result as Object

Tags: sql, symfony, object, prepared-statement

How can I handle a raw sql in symfony 2 which return an Object of a entity?

I need this for using it withing reflectionMethods (invoke) which only works with Object.

Actually I recieve an array:

```
stmt = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
            ->getConnection()
            ->prepare('SELECT '.$neededColumns.' FROM Data '.$sql);


        $stmt->execute();
        $result=  $stmt->fetchAll();`
```

Can I use

```
          $items = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "NameOfBundle\Entity\Content");
```

I stuck so it would be great to get some help from yourside.

Comment: ReflectionMethod only take Objects. So how can I transform this result into objects? For example : $reflectionMethod = new ReflectionMethod('AppBundle\Entity\YourEntity','get'.$soft[0]);
$i[] = $reflectionMethod->invoke($yourObject);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to the Doctrine registry (which is the `$this->getDoctrine()` call that you're making) then you'll want to look into the [Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) feature of Doctrine ORM.

The documentation is fairly extensive but your code will probably look something like:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
$rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('NameOfBundle\Entity\Content', 'alias');

$selectClause = $rsm->generateSelectClause([ 'alias' => 'table_alias' ]);
$sql = 'SELECT '.$selectClause.' FROM table table_alias';

$query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
$object = $query->getOneOrNullResult();
```

Obviously the `$sql` part can be whatever SQL you want, but if you need joined entities then be sure to use `$rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata()` method, again, explained within the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me . Now its clear and fine running. )

Comment: Thanks! That helped me too. You can also set the parameters normally `$query->setParameter('ids', $ids);` after `createNativeQuery`.